# What are the different ways of performing Triangular matrix-vector multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, matrix-equations, discrete-optimization

Suppose we have $$\left[\begin{array}{cccc} x_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ x_2 & x_1 & 0 & 0 \\ x_3 & x_2 & x_1 & 0 \\ x_4 & x_3 & x_2 & x_1 \end{array}\right] \times \left[\begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ y_4 \end{array}\right]$$
Where $x_i, y_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and in the range of $[70,2^{31}-1]$ for $i=1,\dots,4$. In this context we call each $x_i, y_i$ as single precision and $x_iy_j$ as double precision for $j=1,\dots,4$. We have two options of computing this matrix-vector product

1. Single Lower Triangular matrix-vector product
2. Partition into $2\times2$ sub-matrices that results into two Triangular matrix and a Topelitz matrix

The number of operations for each will be

1. $10$M(single precision)+$6$A(double precision)
2. $9$M(single precision)+$3$A(single precision)+$6$A(double precision)

What can be other ways of performing this matrix-vector multiplication? Such that the number of operations change like the above two techniques.

Is there a way of reducing the number of double precision addition?

Comment: Would you elaborate on what you final goal really is. In the past the number of floating point operations was considered the limiting factor and many algorithms are *still* analyzed by counting the number and type of their floating point operations. However, there are many other concerns which can be far more important, such as data locality, memory access pattern, arithmetic intensity, vector potential, as well as the chipset that you are programming for.

Comment: @CarlChristian may be you are right but at this stage we are not considering the underlying machine details.